# Do two matrices commute only if one matrix is the inverse of the other?

Tags: matrices, inverse

Is it safe to say matrix multiplication is commutative ONLY if one matrix is the inverse of the other? The only way I could believe this was the 2 commutative type properties I know of:
$$AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$$
and
$$adj A*A=A*adjA = |A|I$$
where $adj A$ is the adjoint of matrix A.

The first equation when expanded with $A^{-1}=\frac{adjA}{|A|}$ you end up getting the second equation. So both are the same equation. These are the only two properties that explains commutativity as far as I'm aware of(are there any more?) and my conclusion was based on these only. Also multiplication with identity matrix is also commutative but any other counter cases? So is it safe to say matrix multiplication is commutative ONLY if one matrix is the inverse of the other? Thanks!!

Comment: There are infinite commuting matrix examples. You can see infinites examples [here](https://yutsumura.com/find-all-matrices-b-that-commutes-with-a-given-matrix-a-abba/)

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Oh, I see, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any two diagonal matrices commute, because:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a_1&0&\cdots&0\\0&a_2&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\0&0&\cdots&a_n\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}b_1&0&\cdots&0\\0&b_2&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\0&0&\cdots&b_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a_1b_1&0&\cdots&0\\0&a_2b_2&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\0&0&\cdots&a_nb_n\end{bmatrix}$$

and "ordinary" multiplication commutes.

Now, if a matrix $P$ is an arbitrary invertible matrix, and $D_1$ and $D_2$ are arbitrary diagonal matrices, this means that the matrix $P^{-1}D_1P$ will also commute with $P^{-1}D_2P$ because:

$$(P^{-1}D_1P)(P^{-1}D_2P)=P^{-1}D_1D_2P=P^{-1}D_2D_1P=(P^{-1}D_2P)(P^{-1}D_1P)$$

Comment: Yea, your right. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Not at all. For instance, the identity matrix commutes with *every* other square matrix of the same size. As another example, the matrices $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ commute, but none of them is a multiple of the other one.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention about the identity matrix, im aware of that though, any other cases?

Comment: I have expanded my answer.

Comment: So when you multiply $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ with $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ the answer is always 0 right? Are there any more cases that your aware of?

Comment: Sure. Take any two diagonal matrices $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}c&0\\0&d\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. They always commute, whether or not one of them is a multiple of the other one.

Comment: Oh okays, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For any matrix $A$, the matrix $A^n$ whatever be $n$ satisfies $A A^n = A^n A$.

Also for any two real numbers $a, b$ the matrices $1\quad a\choose 0\quad 1$ and $1\quad b\choose 0\quad 1$ can be multiplied in any order to get the same product.

Comment: Wow that's great, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Another commuting matrix examples come from:

> Lemma: Any square matrix $A$ conmutes with a linear combination of itself and the
> identity, that is:
>
> $A\cdot (\alpha A-\beta I)= A \cdot(\alpha A-\beta I)$

Proof:

$$A\cdot (\alpha A-\beta I) = \alpha A^2 -\beta A = A\cdot(\alpha A - \beta I)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Consider mark an answer as correc :-)